# Guarantee uniqueness of speciifc values using REPEATABLE READ

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, isolation-level

we have a simple table:

```
Human:
+------+
|Height|
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

and I have a method that adds a human:

```
@AutoWired 
HumanRepository humanRepo; // JpaRepository

@Transactional(isolationLevel = REPEATABLE_READ)
void addHuman(int height){
    if(humanRepo.existsByHeight(height){
      throw new HumanWithSuchHeightExists();
    }
    humanRepo.save(Human.builder().height(height).build())
}
```

And I would like to guarantee that exists exactly one man with a specific height.

1. Does `REPEATABLE_READ` guarantee that?
2. Is my code (pseudocode) correct to satisfy that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theory says the only isoloation level that is capable of absolute guarantees re. data integrity (wrt declared rules) is SERIALIZABLE.

With REPEATABLE READ, you theoretically are still exposed to the risk of two transactions attempting to insert the same row and the following sequence of events letting that pass :

T1 checks existence of row, row does not exist
T2 checks existence of row, row does not exist
T1 inserts, possibly repeating the existence check for the row (still does not exist)
T2 inserts, possibly repeating the existence check for the row (still does "not exist" because T1 hasn't committed yet so its newly inserted data stay invisible to T2).
T1 commits
T2 commits

REPEATABLE READ, as the name says, only provides guarantees with respect to *existing rows* (namely that *if* a row is found to exist, it won't be altered by other transactions and the read then becomes "repeatable").

Comment: thanks for your response. So, if I replace REPEATABLE_READ with `SERIALIZABLE` it will work?

Comment: It would be nice if it did ...  However it depends a bit on which DBMS engine you're using and whether its semantics of SERIALIZABLE are quite the same as that of the theory.  Google e.g. for an article "Oracle's serializable is not SERIALIZABLE".  If I recall correctly, IBM DB2 also has terminological differences, naming theory's REPEATABLE READ "read stability" and theory's SERIALIZABLE "repeatable read" (!!!).  So you see if you want to know things to the last detail you have a lot of checking to do wrt the behaviour of *every component* of your toolchain (e.g. also the ORM).

Comment: Sorry I cannot know that level of detail of every existing engine around.  (And if your question is DBMS-specific pls tag the question as such.  It helps attracting attention of the people who *do* know that kind of info by heart for the particular engine you're concerned with.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PostgreSQL SERIALIZABLE should prevent creating more than one record with the same height. It will abort either T1 or T2.

I think that the anomaly would be formally called Anti-Dependency Cycle (G2). Here is a [good reference that includes major databases](https://github.com/ept/hermitage)

Also, why not use a [unique constraint](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-unique-constraint/) instead?